# Why appears C# web generation failed?

Tags: database, genexus, reorganize

When I want to create the tables to after see the preview of my job appears this error:

> error: GeneXus C# Generator:
>
> local protection:
>
> Not authorized
>
> Default (C# Web) Generation Failed
>
> error: Error in reorganization
>
> Run Developer Menu Failed

Answer (score 2):

It appears that you don´t have an authorization for the .NET (C#) generator.
If you look at GeneXus License Manager, is it authorized or not?
Check out [this page](http://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?32685,Not%20authorized%20error%20related%20to%20protection,) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

The message speaks of local license so another possibility would be that you have installed your licenses remotely and the License Manager pointing locally as you see in http://www.gxopen.com/forumsr/servlet/viewthread?ARTECH,3,158064

If this is the case proceed as follows:

Open the Genexus License Manager and set there the license of the c # generator pointing to the remote machine by name or IP.-

It should also take into account a series of requirements which I do not detail in depth as it would be too long.

These requirements vary depending on whether the pc server is in the same domain or in the same workgroup as the local pc.-

In particular you should keep in mind things like:

- a) Firewall with its exceptions on port 135 (DCom) and for
  ProtSrv.exe application
- b) User with Remote Access premition for anonymous loggin
- c) Updated DNS

For more information about that last point plese see http://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?19985,Setting+user+permissions+using+remote+licenses,